# mysql display total amount of money - group by day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with amount and date in format: 2020-04-08 19:26:39.000
how should I select data to sum amounts per day?

```
01-06-2020 500
08-06-2020 300

SELECT sum(amount) as total, (date) FROM table group by [date]
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total, 
       DATE(datetime_field) AS `date` 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Studio says I need to convert the date format, i'm struggeling with that...

```
SELECT sum ("amount") as total, CONVERT(datetime, "datefield") as goodformat FROM "tablename" group by "something" order by "something" DESC
```

what i achieve is a column with amount and column with date as a number. that would be fine if I could round the numbers. in excel i could recover the correct date format.

Comment: Confusion, you tagged question as mysql, and here you are saying SQL studio. Please specify which database and version . What is issue with Akina's answer ?? It should work